# Valor e referência em python

Tags: python, matriz, ponteiro, objetos

Desconsiderando a forma como foi feita, este é um código de transposição de matrizes quadradas, a pessoa que fez se deparou com o erro na atribuição dos valores no último **for** e nem eu ou ele consegui resolver: quando a matriz mT recebe os valores da matriz m, através de deepcopy(m) não deveria ter sido eliminado todas as referências? Então por que do erro na hora de atribuir os valores em ***mT[ i ][ j ] = m[ j ][ i ]***

Sabemos fazer a transposição de matrizes de outras formas mas gostaríamos de saber o motivo do erro para aprendizado. Segue o código abaixo:

```
from copy import deepcopy
n = int(input('Digite o tamanho da matriz: '))

linha = [0] * n 
m = [linha] * 2
mT = deepcopy(m) 

print(f'Matriz criada com sucesso: {m}')

for l in range(n):  
    linha = list()
    for c in range(n):
        numero = int( input('Digite um valor para a posição {},{}: '.format(l, c)) )
        linha.append(numero)
    m[l] = linha

for i in range(len(m)):
    for j in range(len(m)):        
       mT[i][j] = m[j][i]

print(f'\nMatriz original: {m}')
print(f'\nMatriz transposta: {mT}')
```

Answer (score 4):

Vamos por partes. Primeiro, vejamos o que acontece quando você multiplica uma lista por um número:

```
lista = [0, 0]
m = [lista] * 2
# m é uma lista contendo 2 listas
print(m) # [[0, 0], [0, 0]]

m[0][0] = 10 # mudar um elemento da primeira lista
print(m) # [[10, 0], [10, 0]] (mudei nas 2 listas)

print(id(m[0]), id(m[1])) # imprimem o mesmo número
```

A variável `m` é uma lista de listas: ela possui 2 elementos, e cada um deles é uma lista. Só que ao fazer `[lista] * 2`, ambas as listas de `m` apontam para a mesma lista. Por isso uma alteração na primeira lista reflete também na segunda, já que ambas apontam para a mesma lista. Tanto que se imprimir o `id`, o resultado será o mesmo número para ambas (segundo a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id), no caso específico do CPython, `id` retorna o endereço do objeto na memória, então no código acima você pode ver que ambos apontam para a mesma lista).

Mas e `deepcopy`, não deveria resolver isso? Não:

```
lista = [0, 0]
m = [lista] * 2
print(m) # [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
print(id(m[0]), id(m[1])) # imprimem o mesmo número

from copy import deepcopy

m2 = deepcopy(m)
print(m2) # [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
print(id(m2[0]), id(m2[1])) # imprimem o mesmo número (não é o mesmo de m)

# mudar um elemento da primeira lista também afeta a segunda
m2[0][0] = 10
print(m2) # [[10, 0], [10, 0]]

# mas m permanece inalterado
print(m) # [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

`deepcopy` criou outra lista (tanto que o `id` dessas listas em `m2` é diferente de `m`), mas `m2` ainda tem a mesma característica: as duas listas que ele possui são referências para a mesma lista.

Isso acontece porque, [segundo a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy), `deepcopy` mantém um dicionário interno de "memória" que guarda os objetos que já foram copiados. Então se ele encontra o mesmo objeto novamente, ele usa esta cópia interna em vez de copiar novamente.

Ou seja, primeiro ele copia a lista que está em `m[0]` e guarda nesta "memória" interna. Quando ele for copiar `m[1]`, verá que é a mesma lista (pois vimos que ambos apontam para o mesmo lugar), então em vez de copiar novamente, ele usa a cópia que está na "memória" interna. O resultado é que `m2` terá 2 referências para a mesma lista.

---

#### Como resolver?

O mais simples é simplesmente não criar a lista usando `*`. Na verdade, como listas em Python são dinâmicas e podem mudar de tamanho conforme a necessidade, você não precisa sequer criá-las com um determinado tamanho. Para que inicializar tudo com zero se depois você vai ler os valores e sobrescrever tudo? Simplesmente adicione os elementos conforme eles forem lidos:

```
n = int(input('Digite o tamanho da matriz: '))

m = []
for linha in range(n):
    lista = []
    for coluna in range(n):
        numero = int(input(f'Digite um valor para a posição {linha},{coluna}: '))
        lista.append(numero)
    m.append(lista)

print(f'Matriz criada com sucesso: {m}')
```

E para criar a matriz transposta, basta iterar por todas as linhas simultaneamente e criar uma lista a cada iteração:

```
mT = []
for elementos in zip(*m):
    mT.append(list(elementos))

print(mT)
```

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) itera por várias listas de uma vez, e a sintaxe `*m` serve para fazer o [*unpacking*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments) da lista `m`. Ou seja, `zip(*m)` é o mesmo que fazer `zip(m[0], m[1], etc..)`, mas para fazer assim eu teria que saber o tamanho de `m`. Usando o *unpacking*, eu não preciso saber a quantidade, todos são passados como argumentos para `zip`.

Então na prática estou passando todas as linhas da matriz para `zip`. Assim, na primeira iteração, `elementos` será uma tupla contendo o primeiro elemento de cada uma das linhas. Na segunda iteração, será uma tupla com o segundo elemento de cada uma, e assim por diante.

Com isso, basta criar uma lista a partir desta tupla e inserir em `mT`. Ao final, temos a matriz transposta.

Se quiser, pode usar também uma [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](/q/192343/112052):

```
mT = [ list(elementos) for elementos in zip(*m) ]
```

---

Enfim, não precisa de `deepcopy` porque não é necessário criar `m` com um tamanho pré-determinado. Mas se quiser **muito** fazer isso, a solução é não usar `*` para criá-la:

```
n = # ler o valor de n

# assim cada sublista é independente (não ocorre o problema de ambas apontarem para a mesma)
m = [ [0] * n for i in range(n) ]

for linha in range(n):
    # Não precisa criar uma outra lista interna
    for coluna in range(n):
        m[linha][coluna] = int(input(f'Digite um valor para a posição {linha},{coluna}: '))

from copy import deepcopy

mT = deepcopy(m)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        mT[j][i] = m[i][j]

print(mT)
```

Repare que como agora `m` já foi criada com o tamanho certo, também não preciso criar outra lista dentro do `for`, pois eu posso atribuir o valor diretamente na posição específica.

Mas eu ainda prefiro criar as listas e adicionar os elementos "sob demanda", em vez de criar a matriz com zeros, preenchê-la, criar um cópia, etc...

Comment: Explicou perfeitamente!! Muito obrigado pela aula!!!

Comment: @AlmirLopesMartins Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema

Answer (score 2):

A cópia foi criada quando o objeto `m` era `[linha] * 2`, no caso uma lista repetida. mT é uma cópia mas ainda assim possui uma lista repetida duas vezes, só não compartilha a referência com m.

Se trocar a criação de mT para outro ponto dá para consertar isso.

```
from copy import deepcopy
n = int(input('Digite o tamanho da matriz: '))

linha = [0] * n 
m = [linha] * 2

print(f'Matriz criada com sucesso: {m}')

for l in range(n):  
    linha = list()
    for c in range(n):
        numero = int( input('Digite um valor para a posição {},{}: '.format(l, c)) )
        linha.append(numero)
    m[l] = linha

mT = deepcopy(m) 

for i in range(len(m)):
    for j in range(len(m)):        
       mT[i][j] = m[j][i]

print(f'\nMatriz original: {m}')
print(f'\nMatriz transposta: {mT}')
```